# Is there any way to get the ranges in a chart series in Office.JS?

Tags: office-js

I am trying to get the ranges containing the chart series data for a chart in Excel. How can I do this? I've looked at the Chart Series object and it doesn't seem to have any properties or methods that support this.

Answer (score 1):

Excel API 1.15 Set will be released in early May, which will have the ChartSeries.getDimensionDataSourceString(Dimension) you need. This method can get the data range of each series on the specific dimension.

You can refer to this link:
*https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/requirement-sets/excel/excel-preview-apis?view=common-js-preview*